# Is there any way to find disconnected (turned off) over a LAN network ? (without using ping)

Tags: linux, shell-script, networking, ping

I am working on a script made for finding computer which are offline,

using ping I can ping those computer and compare the result using if else command.

But I am curious to know, if there any possible way to find out turned off computes over a single lan (192.168.x.[0-254])?

Comment: Any (large) number of computers could be turned off at some point in time...?

Answer (score 0):

If the computer is turned off, it won' t be reachable in any way. It will show up the same as an address that is not in use.

You may want to take a look at tools like [nmap](http://nmap.org) (it should be available as a package for your Linux distribution, it is available for Windows). It's options are intimidating, but it can check a range of addresses for live machines automatically. Be careful, running such checks against foreign networks can be considered an hostile act, as such a check is the first step to mount an attack.